# hadoop distcp not working,MR job in accepted state

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, distcp

I am trying to copy data from CDH4 to CDH5 cluster. When I submit the distcp job from CDH5, MR job goes to accepted state and stays there ( I have tried it multiple times, it stayed there for more than 15 hrs). Data I want to copy is less than 10MB.

Below is the setup and steps I am using.

Source: CDH4,  e.g. NodeName = cloudera4
Destination: CDH5, e.g. NodeName = Cloudera1

Command used on CDH5:
hadoop distcp hftp://Cloudera4:50070/ hdfs://Cloudera1/

Below is the console output:

```
[root@Cloudera1-RD opt]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop distcp hftp://Cloudera4:50070/ hdfs://Cloudera1/

    15/03/05 10:51:23 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[hftp://Cloudera4:50070/], targetPath=hdfs://Cloudera1/, targetPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}
    15/03/05 10:51:23 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at Cloudera1:8032
    15/03/05 10:51:27 INFO Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb
    15/03/05 10:51:27 INFO Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.factor is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor
    15/03/05 10:51:28 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at Cloudera1:8032
    15/03/05 10:51:29 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:18
    15/03/05 10:51:29 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1425491750932_0010
    15/03/05 10:51:30 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1425491750932_0010
    15/03/05 10:51:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Cloudera1:8088/proxy/application_1425491750932_0010/
    15/03/05 10:51:30 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job-id: job_1425491750932_0010
    15/03/05 10:51:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1425491750932_0010
```

This MR job stays in Accepted state forever.

I am stuck with this from many days now.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: There may be more information in resource manager or node manager log. Do a grep 1425491750932_0010 /var/log/hadoop-yarn/*.log on resourcemanger host and node manager host and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Paul, I Tried your suggestion, but now luck. When I grep, I dont gent any result.

Comment: Is this a single node cluster? This may be due to the capacity limit of the cluster. please post your hadoop conf for scheduler, such as /etc/hadoop/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml

Comment: Paul, thanks for the input. This is multi node (3 nodes ) cluster. I gave up migration and finally created new CDH cluster for CDH 5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your [code](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html) is Do not run distcp as the **hdfs user** which is blacklisted for MapReduce jobs by default.

Refer the Link and run distcp

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using:
`hdfs dfs -cp s3://<path> hdfs:///user/livy/`